# rounding into milions in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a code as below and i would like to round it. How to get around with this ? Many thanks in advance.

```
var _result =
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        ABS( _sales ) >= 1000000, FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0,,M vs AOP;-$#,##0,,M vs AOP"),
        ABS( _sales ) >= 1000, FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0,k vs AOP;-$#,##0,k vs AOP"),
        FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0 vs AOP;-$#,##0 vs AOP" )
    )
    RETURN _result
```

Expected Answer:

```
x < 500k   -- x = 0M
y >= 500k  -- y = 1M

a <  1.500M  -- a = 1M
b >= 1.500M  -- a = 2M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
Measure = 
VAR x = SUM('Table'[Column1])
RETURN
IF(x >= 0, FORMAT(x, "$#,0,,M;"), FORMAT(x, "-$#,0,,M;"))
```

Note - multiple format strings can be separated by ; but that won't work for your requirement as -187000 will still show as just 0 without a minus sign. This new measure fulfils your requirements.

[image]

```
Measure = 
VAR x = SUM('Table'[Column1])
RETURN
FORMAT(x, "$#,0,,M")
```

Comment: thanks for the respond, but this code fails for negative numbers: gives 0M for -187k
I need -0M

Comment: I'll update now.